# Windows ListView LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES and per-monitor DPI awareness

Tags: windows, dpi

Does anyone know how to get a standard Windows list view control with LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES to redraw correctly when moved between monitors of different resolution when in per-monitor-v2 mode?

Here's how it looks on the hi-dpi monitor:

[image]

After dragging window to a lo-dpi monitor the checkbox itself has resized but the row height is wrong:

[image]